# What is the format of special section in ELF

Tags: elf

I try to write a program to generate ELF(based on Arm and execute through `qemu-arm`). Most format in ELF has been well illustrated
on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format). But I can't find any spec describe the format of special section(e.g. `.text` `.data`(especially what I want to know)).

I tried to put some initialized global variable in .data section. What format should I write in ELF(.data section) if I have global statement like: `int a = 10;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not special format for `.text` and `.data`.

When the static linker links several `.o` file,

1. it simply concatenates the `.text` and `.data` segments (while resolving relocations)
2. and places them in the final `.so` or executable file according to the linker script (see `gcc  -Wl,-verbose /dev/null`).

The `.data` segment simply contains the initial values of the instanciated global variables.

The `.text` segment simply contains the machine code of the routines/functions.

Let's take this simple C file:

```
char x[5] = {0xba, 0xbb, 0xbc, 0xbd, 0xbe};

char f(int i) {
    return x[i];
}
```

Let's compile it:

```
$ gcc -c -o test.o test.c
```

Let's dump the .data section, using [elfcat](https://github.com/randomstuff/elfcat):

```
$ elfcat test.o --section-name .data | xxd
00000000: babb bcbd be                             .....
```

We can clearly explain the content of .data section.

Let's dump the .text section:

```sh
$ elfcat test.o --section-name .text | xxd
00000000: 5548 89e5 897d fc8b 45fc 4898 488d 1500  UH...}..E.H.H...
00000010: 0000 000f b604 105d c3
```

Let's decompile this:

```sh
$ elfcat test.o --section-name .text > test.text
$ r2 -a x86 -b 64 -qc pd test.text
            0x00000000      55             push rbp
            0x00000001      4889e5         mov rbp, rsp
            0x00000004      897dfc         mov dword [rbp - 4], edi
            0x00000007      8b45fc         mov eax, dword [rbp - 4]
            0x0000000a      4898           cdqe
            0x0000000c      488d15000000.  lea rdx, qword [0x00000013] ; 19
            0x00000013      0fb60410       movzx eax, byte [rax + rdx]
            0x00000017      5d             pop rbp
            0x00000018      c3             ret
```

Again, there is nothing special in the text segment: it only contains the machine code of the routines/functions of my program.

Notice however the relocation and symbol informations in other segments:

```
$ readelf -a test.o
[ ... ]

Relocation section '.rela.text' at offset 0x1b8 contains 1 entry:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
00000000000f  000800000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 x - 4

Relocation section '.rela.eh_frame' at offset 0x1d0 contains 1 entry:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000000020  000200000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 .text + 0

[...]

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 10 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS test.c
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     3: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 
     4: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 
     5: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6 
     6: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    7 
     7: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5 
     8: 0000000000000000     5 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 x
     9: 0000000000000000    25 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 f
```